# DNS zone file question

Tags: dns

I have been researching on how to set up a DNS server and found that BIND seems to be the best way to do so. I am new to setting up a DNS server so I have a couple of questions

If I am only using the DNS server to resolve a web domain to an IP address would I need to create a DNS zone file?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one host I would edit the hosts file.

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

192.168.1.134     webcam.schifer.loc

that is [ip address]     [machine.LANname]